# Separate log files for different webapp in the same servlet container

Tags: java, servlets, logging, web-applications

Suppose I have 2 web applications (A & B) are hosted in the same weblogic server. I define a logging.properties file under /WEB-INF in each web application. The properties file defines a set of log levels for different classes and a file Handler which webapp A writes log to A.log, and webapp B writes log B.log. Standard java.util.logging package is used for logging.

A servlet context listener is defined such that the logging.properties file is read when the context initalized. The code fragment is as following:

```
        InputStream is = sCtx.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/logging.properties");
        LogManager logManager = LogManager.getLogManager();
        logManager.readConfiguration(is);

        Logger rootLogger = Logger.getLogger("");

        SysLogFileHandler fileHandler;
        try
        {
            String location = SysLogFileHandler.getSysLogFilePath();
            String fileName = SysLogFileHandler.LOG_FILE_PREFIX + "%d.log";

            fileHandler = new SysLogFileHandler(location + File.separator + fileName, true);
            fileHandler.setEncoding(Constant.DEFAULT_CHARSET);

            fileHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
            rootLogger.addHandler(fileHandler);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I expect logs from webapp A write to A.log only, and webapp B write to B.log only. However, the outcome is not as expected. All logs from A & B are written to either 1 log file only, depends on which webapp starts at last.

May I ask what's the proper way of having separate log files in webapp environment?

Comment: I'm not weblogic expert, but in general logger classes are loaded by server in the root class loader so you 'll have only one logger manager so it load only one configuration. But you can set configuratoin at server level and create 2 files by namespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default LogManager class then calling [readConfiguration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#readConfiguration(java.io.InputStream)) will reset the logging configuration.

One solution is to use or build a new LogManager that is sensitive to the web classloader like [org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/juli/ClassLoaderLogManager.html) and start the server with that log manager.